# Array's new value is being displayed before being assigned

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I will try to explain my problem in most understandable way.

1. Description
2. Problem

**1. Description**

`tl;dr` console.logging displays array data which is being assigned to it after performing ajax request in the future. Displaying it before assignment!

this is my `js` structure:

```
var details = {
    var contactsData = [];
    [...]

    saveNotes: function() {
     console.log(this.contactsData);
     this.saveDefault();
    }

    saveDefault: function() {
        var that = this;
        $.ajax({
            [...]
        }).done(function (response) {
            that.contactsData[that.contactsData.length] = response;
            console.log(that.contactsData);
    });
}
```

STEP 1: I have an input field. Using event `querySelector` and `keypress` eventListener I call `saveNotes()`

STEP 2: `saveNotes()` console logs `this.contactsData` before calling another function.

STEP 3: I execute `saveDefault()` and call ajax, it returns response which I attach to `contactsData` as a new value and console.log `this.contactsData`.

**2. Problem**

Console.log in SaveNotes() logs this
[image: Consolelog1]

and console log in `.done` logs this

[image: consolelog2]

Note the (26) vs (27) info in inspector and length: value

How this is even possible, help please and thanks.

Comment: I don't see how you can tell the output of the `console.log()` calls apart. It's a good idea to log some sort of label so that it's unambiguous.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057440/is-chromes-javascript-console-lazy-about-evaluating-arrays